# How to reset class in an element if another element is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am sorting a table and using bootstrap glyphicons to show the direction of the sort. I was wondering if there was a way to reset a column to the original glyphicon if another column is clicked.

```js
$('.tablePointer').click(function() {
        $(this).find('i').each(function() {
            var classes = ['glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes', 'glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt'];
            this.className = classes[($.inArray(this.className, classes) + 1) % classes.length];
        });
```

```html
 <th class="tablePointer fontsize-smmd" id="clientSort"><span>Client </span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></th>
        <th class="tablePointer fontsize-smmd" id="subjectSort"><span>Subject </span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></th>
        <th class="tablePointer fontsize-smmd" id="authorSort"><span>Author </span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></th>
        <th class="tablePointer fontsize-smmd" id="dateSort"><span>Creation Date </span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></th>
```

For example, if the client column is originally clicked and the glyphicon is changed to glyphicon-sort-by-attributes, but then the subject column is clicked, how can I reset the glyphicon in the client column to glyphicon-sort while continuing to toggle between glyphicons in the subject column?

Comment: Please post a minimum code to reproduce the issue

Comment: rather than struggling with glyphicons, try using some existing code available under proper license.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class first from all icons, then apply only to the one clicked

See example below (click colored blocks next to column names):

```js
$('.glyphicon-sort').on('click', el => {
  $('.glyphicon-sort').removeClass('glyphicon-sorting');
  $(el.target).closest('.glyphicon-sort').addClass('glyphicon-sorting');
});
```

```css
.glyphicon-sort,
.glyphicon-sorting {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.glyphicon-sort {
  background: blue;
}

.glyphicon-sorting {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<th class="tablePointer fontsize-smmd" id="clientSort"><span>Client </span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></th>
<th class="tablePointer fontsize-smmd" id="subjectSort"><span>Subject </span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></th>
<th class="tablePointer fontsize-smmd" id="authorSort"><span>Author </span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></th>
<th class="tablePointer fontsize-smmd" id="dateSort"><span>Creation Date </span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></th>
```